# How to keep the format of a converted HTML to attributedString?

Tags: html, swift, fonts, nsattributedstring

I have a converted attributedText from HTML. The styles were retained e.g. Bold or Regular but the format wasn't(Heading 1, Heading 2 etc.). The text was set to different Headings but the output of the UILabel ignore this and produces same size.

[This is the supposed format from the API. you can see that the texts 11111111111 are smaller than 222222222222.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxQKq.jpg)

When you see the output in iPhone 5S, the Headings were ignored.

[This is the output in iPhone 5S. the 11111111111 and 2222222222 are same size even though they are in a different format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4d2V.jpg)

The format of 1111111111 is Heading 1 while 22222222222 is Heading 2.

Here is the code I used to convert the HTML to attributedString and change font style too:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension String {

    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }

}

extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func setFontFace(font: UIFont, color: UIColor? = nil) {
        beginEditing()
        self.enumerateAttribute(
            .font,
            in: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length)
        ) { (value, range, stop) in

            if let f = value as? UIFont,
                let newFontDescriptor = f.fontDescriptor
                    .withFamily(font.familyName)
                    .withSymbolicTraits(f.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits) {

                let newFont = UIFont(
                    descriptor: newFontDescriptor,
                    size: font.pointSize
                )
                removeAttribute(.font, range: range)
                addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: range)
                if let color = color {
                    removeAttribute(
                        .foregroundColor,
                        range: range
                    )
                    addAttribute(
                        .foregroundColor,
                        value: color,
                        range: range
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        endEditing()
    }
}




import ImageViewer
import UIKit

class HomeDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Stored

private var feed: Feed?

private func showFeedDetails() {
    categoryName.text = feed?.category
    dateLabel.text = feed?.datePosted
    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(attributedString: (feed?.body?.htmlToAttributedString)!); mutableAttributedString.setFontFace(font: UIFont(name: "Raleway", size: 13)!);
    detailsLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
    collectionView.reloadData()
    startCollectionViewTimer()
}
}
```

Here is the model:

```
import Foundation

struct Feed: Codable {

    var id: Int
    var title: String?
    var category: String?
    var imageList: [String]?
    var bodyPreview: String?
    var body: String?
    var datePosted: String?
    var youtubeLink: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case title
        case category
        case imageList = "images_url"
        case bodyPreview = "preview_body"
        case body
        case datePosted = "date_posted"
        case youtubeLink = "youtube_link"
    }

}
```

Comment: Question, without changing the font and using `setFontFace`, were the different size correctly rendered?

Comment: @LarmeYes the size is correct when rendered